# What are Code Review extensions for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Are there any tools for code review that are compatible with Visual Studio Code? I found CodeStream on VSC marketplace but it doesn't support subversion as repository.

I realize that the questions about tools are generally frowned upon, but Google doesn't understand *Visual Studio Code Code Review* and it is about development tool after all!

Answer (score 1):

[GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) is another great extension. Its not specific to Code Reviews but it could help with process.